# SQL AVG returning an int

Tags: sql, casting, floating-point, average

In one of my queries it appears that the `AVG` function is returning an int.

```
select ..., AVG(e.employee_level)avg_level
```

How do I get it to return floating point values? I tried casting it but all my rows for `avg_level` were still integers.

Comment: The behavior of the AVG() function on integers is not defined in the ANSI standard.  Some databases return an integer; other databases return a float.  To get a float you can use an explicit cast/convert.  Or, what I do is simply multiply by 1.0.

Answer (score 60, accepted):

Try to do it like this:

```
AVG(Cast(e.employee_level as Float)) as avg_level
```

Also i found [this](http://www.tek-tips.com/viewthread.cfm?qid=1512589) topic where you can find some another approach but i not used its and don't know exactly whether works or not.

Comment: @CodeKingPlusPlus - I guess you tried `CAST(AVG(field) AS FLOAT)`?  `AVG(field)` will still return the same answer, which is an INT, by which time casting it to a FLOAT is not going to help you.  `AVG(CAST(field AS FLOAT))`, however, is very different, and probably what you want.  *[+1 to this answer]*

Answer (score 4):

The returned type of the `AVG` depends on the evaluated type of the expression passed to the function.

[image]

For example, if you want your result to be `float`, you need to ensure your column or expression type is `float`.

Answer (score 3):

Casting is more certain, but `...AVG(1.0 * e.employee_level)...` might do it as well, and can be more legible.

Comment: It depends on the RDBMS.  AFAIK many RDBMS treat `1.0` as a fixed point NUMERIC value, not a FLOAT.  Similar effect, possibly even better for this case, but not quite the same.  For this reason I tend to prefer explicit CAST/CONVERT in my code.  Then you *know* what data types things are, rather than relying on data-type precidence and implicit conversions.

Answer (score -1):

AVG(Cast(e.employee_level as DECIMAL(10,O))

THIS WILL WORK IN MYSQL
YOU ARE CATING THE ANS TO GIVE THE VALUE UPTO 0 DECIMALS SO THIS WILL WORK
SUPPOSE THE ANS IS 945.454 SO AVG(Cast(e.employee_level as DECIMAL(10,O)) WILL GIVE 945
AND AVG(Cast(e.employee_level as DECIMAL(10,1)) WILL GIVE 945.5
HOPE YOU GOT THE ANS

Comment: Please provide additional details in your answer. As it's currently written, it's hard to understand your solution.

Comment: Hello and welcome! Please have a look at [Why is it considered inappropriate and unprofessional to type in all capital letters?](https://www.quora.com/Why-is-it-considered-inappropriate-and-unprofessional-to-type-in-all-capital-letters). Thank you.